# Different Contacts of same child Group in multisite

Tags: groups, acl, multisite, drupal-multi-site, domain

I use a multi-site CiviCRM installation with the CiviCRM Multisite extension installed and tuned : having Multi Site Configuration enabled and each site set with a Domain Group.
I set all the proper user's roles in the Drupal permission page for each domain (use of domain access in Drupal 7).

But I struggle with the use of sub-groups.

Let's consider that for the site A-site, the Domain Group is A-group, and for B-site the Domain is Group B-group. Both A-group and B-group are parent group for a same child group C-group.

In one exemple that I have, a C-group that is shared group between different two sites shows a very different number of contacts : one gives 1488 Contacts and the other only 42 Contacts…

**Site A** > Domain Group is **A-group** > is parent of **C-group** > **1488 contacts**

**Site B** > Domain Group is **B-group** > is parent of **C-group** > **42 contacts** (The site B has no access to the missing 1446 contacts)

I cannot explain why there is a difference of contacts that belongs to C-group depending on they are on the A-site or the B-site.

The 42 contacts belongs both to B-group and C-group, the missing 1488 Contacts belong only to C-group.

The CiviCRM Multisite doesn't consider a shared sub-group between sites ?
What is the criteria for a contact to belong to a site or another ? Should I understand that to belong to a (same) sub-group is not the condition to belong to a site ?

Is there a way to include in the selection process the use of sub-groups (child groups) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We totally gave up on using sub-groups with the CiviCRM Multisite. This is too bad but really this seems to be far too complicated and very risky. That would also damage the work of people using different sites.
We use only the Domain Group S-group for Site S to be sure we have the right contact in the right site.